# Customer control's content actual size always return 0 when dynamically change content

Tags: c#, uwp, custom-controls

In my control having content presenter which inside the canvas panel. I have arranged((Align as center, left and right in screen point) the content in canvas based on content actual size. Initial content size loaded properly and when dynamically change content, it actual size always return 0. Due to this, can't align content in screen position. Can you please advise me how to get content size in dynamic case like below scenario

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <!--control style--> 
    <Style TargetType="local:CustomLabel">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomLabel">
                    <Grid>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300" Fill="Red" />
                        </Canvas>
                        <Canvas>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelMargin}"  Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:CustomLabel x:Name="label">
        <local:CustomLabel.Content>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Initial Label" />
            </Grid>
        </local:CustomLabel.Content>
    </local:CustomLabel>
    <Button Content="Change text" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="75" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>

public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Change" });
        this.label.Content = grid;
    }

// control implementation 
public class CustomLabel : Control
{
    bool loadTime = false;
    public CustomLabel()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += CustomLabel_SizeChanged;
    }
    private void CustomLabel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadTime = true;
        CalculateContentPosition();
    }
    private void CalculateContentPosition()
    {
        if (loadTime)
        {
            var content = Content as FrameworkElement;
            if (content != null)
            {
                var left = content.ActualWidth / 2;
                var top = content.ActualHeight / 2;
                this.LabelMargin = new Thickness(300 - left, 300 - top, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    public object Content
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Content.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(CustomLabel), new PropertyMetadata(null,OnContentChanged));
    private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as CustomLabel).CalculateContentPosition();
    }
    public Thickness LabelMargin
    {
        get { return (Thickness)GetValue(LabelMarginProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelMarginProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LabelMargin.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelMarginProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelMargin", typeof(Thickness), typeof(CustomLabel), new PropertyMetadata(new Thickness(1)));
}
```

Comment: Have u resolved your issue by my reply?

Comment: Yes, in this case it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because you access its size too early, it even has not been rendered on XAML page. You might ask why the Grid has size on XAML page at first time. It's because the parent panel has done this operation(similar `Measure(size)`) when it layouts its child elements.

So, to solve your question, you could register the `LayoutUpdated` event of your 'CustomLabel'. Then, in its event handler, you could call `CalculateContentPosition()` method, instead of calling in `OnContentChanged` method.

```
public CustomLabel()
{
    this.SizeChanged += CustomLabel_SizeChanged;
    this.LayoutUpdated += CustomLabel_LayoutUpdated;
}

private void CustomLabel_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
{
    CalculateContentPosition();
}
```